# SQL Server 08 R2: Select Query with complex joins runs slower with Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a Select Query with complex joins which runs less than 2 seconds but if I run the same Query with `Order by` its taking 5 and half minutes even with Indexes on

Below is my table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [check_for_attachments] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [created_at] [datetime] NULL,
    [reference_id] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [status_display_name] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [submitted_file_content_type] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [submitted_file_name] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [submitted_file_size] [bigint] NULL,
    [updated_at] [datetime] NULL,
    [currency_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [recipient_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [sender_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [submitted_file_data_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [transport_file_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [type_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [dtype] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [created_by] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [updated_by] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [is_digitally_signed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [qi_is_quick_invoice] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ready_for_purge] [bit] NULL,
    [qi_summ_attachm_content_type] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [qi_summary_attachment_name] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [qi_summary_attachment_size] [bigint] NULL,
    [qi_summ_attachm_file_data_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [draft_reference_id] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [submitted_at] [datetime] NULL,
    [client_user_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [instance_version] [bigint] NULL,
    [submitted_currency] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [related_invoice_parcel_id] [bigint] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

below are my indexes

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FK_P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL_currency_id] ON [dbo].[P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL] 
(
    [currency_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FK_P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL_qi_summ_attachm_file_data_id] ON [dbo].[P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL] 
(
    [qi_summ_attachm_file_data_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FK_P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL_recipient_id] ON [dbo].[P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL] 
(
    [recipient_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FK_P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL_related_invoice_parcel_id] ON [dbo].[P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL] 
(
    [related_invoice_parcel_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FK_P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL_sender_id] ON [dbo].[P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL] 
(
    [sender_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FK_P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL_submitted_file_data_id] ON [dbo].[P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL] 
(
    [submitted_file_data_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FK_P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL_type_id] ON [dbo].[P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL] 
(
    [type_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL_created_at_id] ON [dbo].[P_LAWFIRM_INVOICE_PARCEL] 
(
    [id] ASC,
    [created_at] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

If I run a complex join select query with `Order by created_at asc, id asc` its taking 5 and half minutes. I checked the query execution plan and it says `99.7% cost` for `Sort`operation.

I tried Rebuilding and Reorganizing all indexes but still there is no improvement on query execution time with `Order by created_at asc, id asc` Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: how much data is involved here? sorting usually can't be done until the full result set is available, meaning the result has to be cached. tons of data = tons of cache

Comment: You could try a CLUSTERED INDEX on created_at and id? The important thing to understand is that your data is ordered in a particular way on the hard drive. If an ORDER BY clause conflicts with this natural ordering then your data will have to be resorted before it can be returned to you.

Comment: Did you try indexing just a date column without id column?

Comment: @MarcB Actual row count is `758,312`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I tried indexing with just date column and there is no improvement it took 6 minutes to execute the query

Comment: @MarcB  Can I alter my CLUSTERED INDEX or do I have to drop and recreate it? are there any consequences of altering CLUSTERED INDEX?

Comment: You can definitely alter/rebuild it and there are consequences but they may not be dire. If most of the queries that access the table use both created_at and id (in that order) then this could only help you. If most queries DON'T use those two columns then this could drastically slow down everyone else.